# Loop through the contents of a specific element in JSON response using PHP

Tags: php, json, loops

I need to loop through one large element in a JSON object which is a response from an API call.  One version of the API gives a response with information nested into a large element called `statuses` and the other does not. I can print a specific key/value on the one that is not nested - but I am having trouble with the one that is.

## Here are examples of each response:

### First, with no nesting:

```
    [
      {
        "created_at": "xzy",
        "id": 123abc,
        "id_str": "123abc",
        "text": "Hello world"
        ...
        ...
        ...
      },
      {
        "created_at": "xzy",
        "id": 123abc,
        "id_str": "123abc",
        "text": "Hello world"
        ...
        ...
        ...
      }
    ]
```

This is put into php array with standard

`$string is defined below, I'm using a Twitter API wrapper link [here](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php)

```
    $string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
```

I can return all of the `id` values with a simple foreach loop like this:

```
    foreach ($string as $items)
    {
      echo "The id from the response is: ".$items['id']."br />";
    }
```

This give me something like this:

> The id from the response is: 123abc
>
> The id from the response is: abc123
>
> The id from the response is: xyz321
>
> ...

### The other version of the API's reponse (the one I need to use) has similar information but stored in a large element `statuses`

```
    {
      "statuses": [
        {
          "created_at": "xzy",
          "id": 123abc,
          "id_str": "123abc",
          "text": "Hello world"
          ...
          ...
          ...
        },
        {
          "created_at": "xzy",
          "id": 123abc,
          "id_str": "123abc",
          "text": "Hello world"
          ...
          ...
          ...
        }
      ],
      "search_metadata": {...}
    }
```

When I try to loop through this json, I never get any output.

The json has been put into `$string` with `json_decode`, same as before.

It's obvious that the information is structured the same, just nested in `statuses`. Here is what I have tried:

```
    foreach($string['statuses'] as $items)
    {
      echo "The id's from the response are: ".$items['id']."br />";
    }
```

As well as:

```
    foreach($string[0] as $items)
    {
      echo "The id's from the response are: ".$items['id']."br />";
    }
```

And:

```
    foreach($string as $items)
        {
          foreach ($items as $statuses => $tweets)
          {
            if (is_array($tweets))
            {
              foreach ($tweets as $t => $v)
              {
                $output[$statuses.'_'.$t] = $v
              }
            }
            else {$output[$statuses] = $tweets;}
          }

        }

     print_r($output);
```

I simply need to loop through the contents of `statuses` as if it weren't even there like in the first response, but nothing is working.

Comment: Do you use `true` with `json_decode`?

Comment: Not sure why you call your decoded array `$string` but it works: https://3v4l.org/3OdhR

Comment: Also note that json_decode returns an array, not a string. The input is a string, but the return is an array.

Comment: I do not use true with it because I'm using a Twitter API php wrapper that specifies it to be written as `json_decode($twitter->setGetField($getfield)` where those methods are defined in another file.

Comment: Then make a copy of the variable and use true on one of them for the output or switch the code to object style `->`

Comment: Like this?  `$new_copy = json_decode($string, true);` ?

Comment: `"id": 123abc,` is not valid JSON, `json_decode()` should be failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code actually does work. I just wasn't seeing any output from the json because the id is a data type that cannot be concatenated, at least not in the way I was doing it. There is an `"id"` element and a string version `"id_str"` and the string version showed up on my web page.

```
foreach($string['statuses'] as $items)
{
  echo "The id's from the response are: ".$items['id']."br />";
}
```

To be clear, this is the snippet that achieved my goal:

```
foreach($string['statuses'] as $items)
{
  echo "The id's from the response are: ".$items['id_str']."br />";
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `$items['id']`? Numbers and strings can both be concatenated. If it's not one of those, you should have gotten a warning (make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` enabled when you're debugging).

Comment: The IDs seem to be the same in the nested version as the unnested version, why did it work with one but not the other?